# Python launcher fails to connect when using Visual Studio Code on a Windows 10 pc

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, launcher

I'm just getting started again with Python and trying to get HelloWorld.py working.

I start VSC (Visual Studio Code) from the command line with "code ." from within the HelloWorld directory.

VSC opens, as does a Windows PowerShell. I run HelloWorld.py without debugging, get another PowerShell and after a while I get a popup that says "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect".

In the Powershell, "py --version" gets me "Python 3.8.5", and "py ./HellowWorld.py" gets me "Hello World".

Here's the python code:

```
msg = "Hello World"
print(msg)
```

Here's the launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]
```

}

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what is the command `py`? Python files are run with `python filename.py`

Comment: py.exe runs the latest version of python. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/faqs

Comment: @Hal Heinrich Is the current system of your computer in another compatible mode? If not, Since the debug function is provided by python, you could try to close other extensions in VSCode, or even install python extension again.